# When bundling an initramfs with a kernel, where should the INITRAMFS_IMAGE variable get set?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, initramfs

I am currently setting `INITRAMFS_IMAGE="core-image-custom-initramfs"` in my `local.conf` and things are working fine. However, I would prefer to move this out of the `local.conf` and it is not clear to me what other options there are besides a custom machine.conf file.

The yocto documentation for [building an initial RAM filesystem (initramfs) image](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/building.html#building-an-initial-ram-filesystem-initramfs-image) states:

```
"...set the INITRAMFS_IMAGE variable in the recipe that builds the kernel image."
```

This suggests to me that `INITRAMFS_IMAGE` should be set in the kernel build recipe. Is my understanding of the documentation correct?